# JavaScript to control checkbox selection in interactive PDF files

Tags: javascript, pdf, checkbox, adobe, adobe-indesign

I am creating a series of checkboxes in an interactive PDF, and I have added Javascript action to clear all other options once one is selected. Checkbox 1, once clicked, clears checkboxes 2 through 4.

I understand this is essentially a Radio button, but for the purpose of the PDF, the user needs to be able to unselect an option and to be able to clear all the options without adding a 'clear all' button.

The Javascript I'm adding is:
this.resetForm(["name", "name1", "name2", "name3", "name4"]);

I'm wondering if there is additional code I could add, so the form ignores the reset action on itself?

With this, I could apply the Javascript to all the checkboxes at once instead of going in and adding the Javascript reset form to each individual checkbox.

Apologies if this question is really simple, I have little Javascript experience.

Thanks in advance,
Marty

Comment: That is the correct code to reset just the fields named in the array to their defaults. Is it not doing what you expect?

Comment: @joelgeraci — Correct this is the code I am applying to reset the fields, and it is working. However, I am wondering if there is a way to add additional code so that the checkbox does not reset itself. For example, this reset code:
 
this.resetForm(["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]); 

will be applied to checkboxes 1 through 6, and I am wondering if there is additional code that I can add so that it will 'ignore itself.' If the reset is applied in bulk to all checkboxes, then it will apply the reset but ignore the reset command on itself (self being the individual checkbox).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use checkboxes to achieve the behavior you want. You can actually create radio buttons that toggle off when the selected item is clicked. Create the radio buttons as normal and then add the following script to the Mouse Up action...

```
if (previousValue == event.target.value) {
    this.resetForm(event.target.name);
}
```

and the following code to the Mouse Down action...

```
var previousValue = event.target.value;
```

You can see a working example [here.](https://practicalpdf.com/techniques/ToggleRadioButtons.pdf)

Answer (score -2):

To unchecked single checkbox,

- document.getElementById("checkboxId").checked = false; (JS)
- $('#checkboxId').prop('checked', false); (JQuery 1.6+)

Seems it should behave like radio buttons. So you can pass the id of selected checkbox to method and only check it.

```js
function invokeClear(item){
   var inputList = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
   
   for (var i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++) {
       if (inputList[i].type == 'checkbox' && inputList[i].id != item ) {
           inputList[i].checked = false;
       }
   }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="cb1" class="cb-element" onclick="invokeClear(this.id)"/> Checkbox  1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="cb2" class="cb-element" onclick="invokeClear(this.id)"/> Checkbox  2<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="cb3" class="cb-element" onclick="invokeClear(this.id)"/> Checkbox  3
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please read the question from the OP again, this is not about HTML and JavaScript but about Interactive PDF and JavaScript. It is specific to the JavaScript used by PDF files. As a result your answer is not relevant for this question.

Comment: Acrobat has its own JavaScript object model which is quite different from the HTML object model.The JavaScript Core is the same.